# Type of clause question ?

Tags: single-word-requests, differences, grammatical-number

No matter what they say about him, **it's false.**

introductory phrase followed by comma and it's false.

So is the whole sentence acting as the main clause in these constructions ? It's false can't stand alone, right.

Comment: Why do you think _it's false_ can't stand alone?

Comment: It's or It is. Doesn't feel like a definitive subject to me. So I wasn't sure. I thought you needed something like: It's false information (ect).

Comment: Technically wasn't sure what 'It's represents'. It's refering back to something mentioned previously in the sentence but other than that. Certainly doesn't stand alone  out of context.

Comment: _It_ is a pronoun that, in this case, refers to _what they say about him_.   In your example of _It's false information_,  _It_ is still the subject and _false information_ is the object -- that which _it_ is.

Comment: _It is_ can certainly stand on its own -- I might see you and, having nothing better to talk about, might say _It's raining._  But, yes, generally speaking, a pronoun must refer to something specific previously discussed.  Consider this conversation: "Did you hear that Joe was eaten by a bear?"  "It's false."  In this case, _it_ refers to the story about Joe.  On the other hand, if someone simply walked up to you and said "It's false", that would be grammatically correct but you would probably respond with "What's false?"